# How do I find inventory that was brought in for a specific customer

Tags: sql

I have three customers that no longer do business with us and I want to find if we are holding anything in inventory that we brought in specifically for them and only them. SQL. Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If you could provide sample data and your expected result that will help. Also, what database are you using (MySQL, Oracle, etc...)

Comment: Can you add a clarification for the relevant part of your database? No help can be given without knowing more about your situation

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory
WHERE CustomerName = 'Mike' || CustomerName = 'Ross' || CustomerName = 'John';
```

Explanation:

This is a sample query where the table is called *Inventory* and *CustomerName* is a field in this table which hold the names of the customers.

Replace the sample names with the names you need.